# Does Apple design its own CPUs?

Tags: cpu, design

We're having a little debate here at work.

Does Apple design its own CPUs? And by CPU design I mean [what is on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_design).

I'm also interested to know the [manufacturers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_manufacturing) of Apple's CPUs/[SoC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_on_a_chip) (maybe even GPUs)

Answer (score 2):

Apple is known to design the ARM used in the iDevices. But Apple definitely does not design everything. For example the GPU is a [PowerVR G6430](http://anandtech.com/show/7335/the-iphone-5s-review/7) and the ARM architecture is derived of [ARM's V8-A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARMv8-A#ARMv8-A).

On the Desktop/Laptop it's done by Intel since it's their CPU.

Apple's latest A7 are made by [Samsung](http://techcrunch.com/2013/09/20/chipworks-apples-a7-chip-made-by-samsung-m7-co-processor-by-nxp/), but it's [believed](http://www.theverge.com/2013/9/20/4752790/apples-a7-processor-is-reportedly-made-by-samsung-at-least-for-now) to shift to other manufacturers (for example TSMC) since Samsung is a major competitor for Apple.